# How to show that closed balls is not bounded in the space of all bounded functions?

Tags: metric-spaces, sequence-of-function

Show that closed balls is not bounded in the space of all bounded functions.

Let X be infinte. And let B(X) be the set of all bounded functions f:X$\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ on X.

and equip it with the metric

d(f,g)=sup $\left \{ |f(x)-g(x)| : x\in X \right \}$

Show that for r>0 and $f\in$ B(X) the closed ball $B_{r}(f)$ is not compact.

I think I have to find a sequence of functions such that its limit is not bounded .
If I consider $f_n:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n$(x)= $\frac{n}{nx+1}$ then

|$f_n$|$\leq$n and the point wise limit f(x)=1/x is not bounded in (0,1) but can't put it into a closed ball. Please help me to find this closed ball or if there is any other example you can also provide that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ be a countably infinite subset of $X$ and for $n \in \Bbb{N}$ let $f_n : X \to \Bbb{R}$ be a function such that
$$f(x_n) = r, \quad f(x) = 0, \forall x \in X \setminus \{x_n\}.$$
Then $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence in the closed ball $B_r(X)$ which has no convergent subsequence since $d(f_m,f_n) = r$ for all $m \ne n$.